# check if the pwd is / in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script which will "cd .." until either a directory is found containing another specific directory, or the "/" directory is reached.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
while test -d REQUIRED_DIR || [[ "$PWD" != "/" ]];do cd ..; done
```

The goal is to find the `REQUIRED_DIR` or stop navigating when the root directory is reached.

Below is the bash code which does not work.

```
while if [ "$PWD"=="/" ];then echo $PWD;false;else true;fi
do
        cd ..
        #echo `pwd`
done
```

The if condition always passes even when not inside root directory.

UPDATE:- the "if" works as expected when i leave space b/w the "==" sign like this
 `[ "$PWD" == "/" ]`.

Answer (score 7):

`while if` is a new one on me, I'm not sure entirely what you're trying to achieve by combining them.

I think you may want to just try `while` on it's own:

```
while [[ "$PWD" != "/" ]] ; do
    cd ..
done
```

or you could just try the much simpler:

```
cd /
```

If, as indicated in your comment, you *need* to do it piecemeal so that you either end up in the first directory containing a `$REQUIRED_DIR` or `/` if you don't find one, you can simply do something like:

```
while [[ "$PWD" != "/" ]] ; do
    if [[ -d "$REQUIRED_DIR" ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: thanks, "while if" is actually a "while EXPRESSION" kind of, so based on the truth value of "if" expression the while decides to continue or quit. I can not use "cd /", because my goal is not to move to "/" dir, actually i want to write a script like "while test -d REQUIRED_DIR || [[ "$PWD" != "/" ]];do cd ..; done". The goal is to find the REQUIRED_DIR and navigating till the root directory is reached.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit, you might have mentioned that in the original question :-) Check out the update for a solution to that problem.